# Counting in Solr

Tags: solr

I am storing the following document in Solr:

```
  doc {
    id: string; // this is a unique string that looks like an md5 result
    job_id: string; // this also looks like an md5 result -- this is not unique
    doc_id: number; // this is a long number -- this is not unique
    text: string; // this is stored, indexed text -- this is not unique
  }
```

Now what I want to do is count the number of docs (doc_id) that have the text foo in them. So if this was SQL I would want to issue something like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct doc_id)
FROM Doc
WHERE text like '%foo%';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some basic Solr configuration already, or you just started thinking about use of Solr?

Comment: Hi @Fuxi, have a full blown Solr Cloud implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work (using [Result Grouping/Filed collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)) you need some conditions to fulfil.

- You have to make your text query ("%foo%") to work in regular search
- doc_id have to be string, you can have copy of that field and call it doc_id_str

Then you can make request like that:

```
/select/?q=foo&rows=0&group=true&group.field=doc_id_str&group.limit=0&group.ngroups&group.format=simple&wt=json
```

This query works for me. How would it work for you, depends on your index and size of it.
Please ask if you need some more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Similar operation to `count (distinct fieldName)` is not possible in Solr right now. There are issues ([SOLR-1814](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1814) and [SOLR-2242](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2242)) related to this problem in Jira. Maybe reading comments in the issues will help you.